# c# path format not supported writealllines

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to make a little Windows-Forms quiz-application for my internship and I'm stuck at saving the results to a save file. This is the code I use:

```
string desktopPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory);

System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(desktopPath + @"\saveFile_" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + ".txt", saveFile);
```

When I click the button to save to a new text-file it crashes and tells me that the path format isn't supported.

How can I correct it so that it saves to a new text-file on the desktop?

Comment: `DateTime.Now.ToString()` will contain a `:` which is an [illegal file name character](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.io.path.getinvalidfilenamechars(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: on a side note, I would not be happy if any application dumped files to my desktop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DateTime.Now.ToString()` will result in a string similar to `30.01.2017 10:30:00` or `01/30/2017 10:30:00`.

`:` is an [invalid file name character](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.io.path.getinvalidfilenamechars(v=vs.110).aspx) so you need to get rid of it, e.g by formatting the timestamp it manually:

```
string filename = "saveFile_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss") + ".txt"
```

Also, I'd advise against building paths with `+`, there is a builtin function for that:

```
System.IO.Path.Combine(desktopPath, filename);    
// or if you have another folder for those files
System.IO.Path.Combine(desktopPath, "FolderX", filename);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace slashes with dashes:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString().Replace("/", "-");
```